# Guidance for a CAD model of a product

Tags: design, cad

[image: Atmospheric Water Generator]
Hi Everyone! I am a novice in CAD modeling, and I am familiar with only two CAD tools - Autodesk fusion 360 and Solidworks. I want to make a CAD model of a product with the outer pod or shell as seen on the left and all the components inside it seen on the right. I don't have an engineering drawing, so that I will be eyeballing the dimensions, I guess. I want some advice on which would be the best possible way to go about this.
Why would I want to make a CAD model? Because I want to make a working prototype of the product and run some simulations to design the blade geometry and the inlet port for the wind to enter to maximize air flow. Is there a tool where I can design the outer shell only and then pick up 3d models of different blade geometries and chuck them inside the shell? Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Yes, pretty much any of the 3D solid modelling software packages.

Comment: Solidworks and fusion360 are both ideal tools for this. Just do your best to re-created the parts and put them together in an assembly. Keep in mind that you may have to model some off the shelf parts just so you can see how they'll fit. For these I often label them as "stub" parts and I don't worry about the exact geometry, as long as the exterior dimensions and mounting holes are correct.